# How to sum total from two different variables in the same column

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I want to sum the volume for x stocks on all days.
My table (stockData) looks like this:

```
DATE        SYMBOL      PRICE       VOLUME
2016-09-21      AAP     146.33      1116964
2016-09-21      AMZN    789.74      2718644 
2016-09-21      AN      47.62       1025741
2016-09-21      AZO     751.45      592877
2016-09-21      BBBY    43.11       3504367
2016-09-21      CBS     50.08       7149860
2016-09-21      CCL     45.82       4510931
2016-09-21      CMG     399.75      924212
2016-09-21      COH     36.03       3181106
2016-09-21      DG      72.18       3098500
2016-09-20      AAP     145.89      1197144
2016-09-20      AMZN    780.22      1937164
2016-09-20      AN      48          459415
2016-09-20      AZO     744.06      362168
2016-09-20      BBBY    43.05       2198117
2016-09-20      CBS     49.97       8364371
2016-09-20      CCL     46.19       4927654
2016-09-20      CMG     400.42      1490731
2016-09-20      COH     35.84       2230159
2016-09-20      DG      71.72       2792748
2016-09-19      AAP     148.44      972161
2016-09-19      AMZN    775.1       2297221
2016-09-19      AN      48.38       797548
2016-09-19      AZO     746.35      382199
2016-09-19      BBBY    43.34       2067412
2016-09-19      CBS     51.08       3319275
2016-09-19      CCL     45.9        4709323
2016-09-19      CMG     402.76      1139757
2016-09-19      COH     35.94       4287905
2016-09-19      DG      71.83       4096195
```

I want to know the total value traded each day for AMZN and COH combined.

The result should look as following:

```
Date             ValueTraded
2016-09-21       2,261,637,161.74 
2016-09-20       1,591,342,994.64 
2016-09-19       1,934,683,302.80
```

I am using dbBrowser for SQLite

I can return a new column called ValueTraded within the select statement, but I cannot figure out where to put the sum, any help would be appreciated.

```
select Date, Price * Volume as ValueTraded
from stockData
where symbol IN ("AMZN", "COH")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `sum()` and `group by`:

```
select Date, sum(Price * Volume) as ValueTraded
from stockData
where symbol in ('AMZN', 'COH')
group by date;
```

Comment: Amazing.  I just arrived at the answer and yours is the exact same.  Thank you!